# react native Push Notification error: Cannot invoke method get() on null object

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, push-notification

i using the npm module https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

I did the steps which are in the readme.
I just want to send push Notification from my backend to the App. So I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Or is this not a good idea?
I registered my app there and i had to paste these code in the build gradle files.

```
(<project>/build.gradle):
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
  }
}
(<project>/<app-module>/build.gradle):
dependencies {
  // Add this line
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}
...
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

after doing these steps i get error: "Cannot invoke method get() on null object" when run this app with react native.

I tried to open the project with android studio but same error message. Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid that error by upgrading `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to `3.1.0`

And you can do that by going to:

```
// project/build.gradle

buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' // <- Here

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
  }
}
```

now you project should sync fine!